# ListStyle weirdness in iOS 15

Tags: swiftui

iOS 15 has messed up the appearance of some of my lists. Try this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
//    let arrayOfStuff = ["Horse","Cow","Screwdriver","Blender","Pyramid","Scotch Tape","Baseball card","CD","Checkbook","Fountain pen","Pin cushion","Couch","Potatos","Protractor"]
    let arrayOfStuff = ["Horse","Cow","Screwdriver","Blender"]
@State var currentlySelectedItem = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.red)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            List {
                ForEach(arrayOfStuff, id: \.self){ item in
                    Text(item)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            currentlySelectedItem = item
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(currentlySelectedItem == item ? Color.gray : Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                }
            }
//            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When running with the plain list style, the area of the frame that doesn't include any rows becomes transparent. When running with the GroupedListStyle, the empty area stays white. That's the behavior I want, but I want the tighter margins of the plain list style. It was all working fine in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try "attaching" the `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` to the `ForEach` not the `List`

Comment: Aha!! That worked! Thank you thank you! It appears that ListStyles in iOS15 are different than in 14. In 15, the plain list style looks more like the grouped style – the highlight doesn't extend to the end of the list and there's a bunch of extra padding at the top of the list. Any idea if those are changeable?

Comment: if my answer addressed your question, could you mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also a shorter form:

```
.listStyle(.plain)
```

Just my 2 cents if someone else arrives here:
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())

does NOT work if You use Section

try usign apple sample:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/displaying-data-in-lists

simply that style has no effect, it maintains grouped if You use Sections.